# Happen to/with doesn't happen often

Tags: word-choice

Would a native speaker say both "happen to" and "happen with" and "often" at the end of my sentence in this context?

"Yes, she sometimes suffers from insomnia. It happens to/with everyone, but it doesn't happen often."

Comment: _Happens to_ is the most usual, I think, but _happens with_ is acceptable. It's not clear whether 'not often' refers to 'her' or 'everyone'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I mean it doesn't often happen to everyone. Is the position of "often" at the end of the sentence unusual?

Comment: I think it's the repetition of _happen_ that reads oddly. I'd suggest "It happens to everyone, but not [very] often".